# Having an issue with setting focus on first error

Tags: javascript, html

```
function validateFirst(first)
{   
    if (first == "")
    {
        error += "\nPlease enter your name";
        first.focus();
    }
}

function errorMessage()
{
    if (error != "")
    {
            alert("The following data was be entered correctly: \n " + error);
            error = "";
    }
    else
    {
        document.write("Thank you for submitting your information");
    }
}
```

My focus won't work. I have this function in my js file. I call it over to my html

```
function validateAll()
{

    var first = document.form.first.value;

    first = validateFirst(first);

    errorMessage();
}
```

I need this to focus on the first error message once the submit button is clicked and the alert box pops up.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: "first" does not exist within the scope if your validateFirst function. It is a private variable within the validateAll function. You need to read-up on how variable scoping works in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
//change 1
function validateFirst(elem)
{   
    if (elem.value == "")
    {
        error += "\nPlease enter your name";
        elem.focus();
    }
}

//change 2
function validateAll()
{

    var elem = document.form.first;

    validateFirst(elem);

    errorMessage();
}
```